# Read Delivery Failure email ID

Tags: sql, vba, email, outlook

I have a macro for reading Email body which is triggered from MS Outlook rules.

Every Email is read but Email from 'Microsoft Outlook' which is a delivery failure email sent by MS exchange server.

I need to read this item to get the email ID which is causing the bounce back.

```
Sub VBS_GetEmailFromBodyText(anItem AsOutlook.MailItem)

'Email parameters
fromID = anItem.SenderName
toList = anItem.To
emailsubject = anItem.Subject
emailBody = Left(anItem.Body, 10)
receiveTime = anItem.ReceivedTime

'create query String
sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO [myDB].[dbo].[VBStestTable](fromID,toList,emailsubject,emailBody,receiveTime) Values('"& fromID & "','"& toList & "','"& emailsubject & "','"& emailBody & "','"& receiveTime & "')"


'SQL connection code
'------------------------

ConstadOpenStatic = 3

ConstadLockOptimistic = 3

objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

objRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

objConnection.Open( _

"Provider = SQLOLEDB; "& _

"Data Source=MyServer;"& _

"Trusted_Connection=Yes;"& _

"InitialCatalog=MyDB;"& _

"User ID=myUser;Password=myPassword;")

'-------------------------

'ended SQL Connection code

　

'RUN SQL Query --Insert records into DB

objRecordSet.Open(sqlQuery, _

objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic)

' Close the DB Connection

objConnection.Close()   　

EndSub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What code do you use now for reading and parsing the message body now?

The Outlook object model provides three main ways for working with item bodies:

1. [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865304(v=office.15).aspx) -  a string representing the clear-text body of the Outlook item.
2. [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941(v=office.15).aspx) - a string representing the HTML body of the specified item.
3. [Word editor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) - the Microsoft Word Document Object Model of the message being displayed. The WordEditor property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Document class from the Word object model which you can use to set up the message body.

You can read more about all these ways in the [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx). It us up to you which way is to choose to read the message body.